# C++ string to char* array struct

Tags: c++, string, char

I have been pulling my hair out on this particular issue and would like some advice. I have the following struct:

```
struct MqlStr // MQL String Array
{
int               len;
char              *string;
};
```

this is being passed to a function as a pointer from an external application as such:

```
MT4_EXPFUNC double __stdcall CheckExecutionRequests(MqlStr* RequestInfo)
```

within the function i am generating a number of string values that i need to assign to varies elements of the MqlStr array. the following works fine:

```
RequestInfo[1].string = "1";
RequestInfo[2].string = "2";
```

but when i use strcpy to get my generated string value into the array, it overwrites the entire array with the value i copied. for example:

```
string field1 = value.substr(Demark + 1, Demark2 - Demark - 1);
strncpy(RequestInfo[1].string, field1.c_str(), field1.size());

string field2 = value.substr(Demark + 1, Demark2 - Demark - 1);
strncpy(RequestInfo[2].string, field2.c_str(), field2.size());
```

if field1 = 1 and field2 = 2 then the entire RequestInfo[] array would be equal to 2 (the last value copied)

can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try field1 = "a" and field2 = "b", my guess is that the entire RequestInfo will still be 222...22

Comment: so i have got to the bottom of this. the problem is that the application which is allocating the memory for this array is not doing it properly. as such any attempt to modify it corrupts the memory. as this application is outside of our control, we will have to look at a workaround for this. in case anyone else is searching, application is Metatrader 4 (MT4)

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestInfo[1] = "1";
```

is not doing what you think. It's either

```
RequestInfo[1].string = "1";
```

if `RequestInfo` is a vector of `MqlStr` objects containing at least 2 elements, or

```
RequestInfo->string = "1";
```

if `RequestInfo` is a pointer to a single `MqlStr` object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated enough space for the .string pointers in your RequestInfo elements? strncpy is not allocating the space for you, use strdup for that.

Comment: the external application that generates the original reference pads each element of the array out with 256 characters to ensure enough space for another allocated to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage `MqlStr` memory in a safe manner, this can happen by using a standard container like `std::string` or by writing methods to allocate and deallocate the internal memory.

Here is an example of a simple class that manages its internal memory:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

struct MqlStr
{
public:
    int    len;
    char  *string;

    MqlStr() { init   (); }
   ~MqlStr() { dealloc(); }
    void assign(std::string& str) {
        dealloc();
        string = new char[str.length() + 1];
        strncpy(string, str.c_str(), str.length());
        string[str.length()] = 0;
        len = str.length();
    }
    void dealloc() {
        if(string != 0) delete [] string; init();
    }

private:
    void init() { string = 0; len = 0; }
         MqlStr(const MqlStr &);
    void operator= (const MqlStr &);
};

double CheckExecutionRequests(MqlStr* RequestInfo)
{
    static int callCount = 0;
    std::ostringstream stringstream; stringstream<<"callCount: "<<callCount++;
    std::string field1 = stringstream.str();
    RequestInfo->assign(field1);
    return 1.0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MqlStr s[5];

    std::cout<<"First call"<<std::endl;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i)
        CheckExecutionRequests(s + i);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i)
        std::cout<<"MqlStr["<<i<<"].string = "<<s[i].string<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"Second call"<<std::endl;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i)
        CheckExecutionRequests(s + i);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i)
        std::cout<<"MqlStr["<<i<<"].string = "<<s[i].string<<std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The second execution of CheckExecutionRequests with the same MqlStr instances will not corrupt the memory. 
An extension to the code can be preallocation of the string size, and only reallocating the memory in the assign method if the new str.length > this.maxLength (preallocated length different from the string size).
The copy constructor and assignment operator are currently disabled, because they can cause problems if not implemented properly while managing internal memory on the heap.

A simpler solution would be to write your struct using a standard container as follows:

```
struct MqlStr
{
public:
    std::string string;
}
```

And then just assign the string you get for the fields to `MqlStr` string.